# Error with Syntax for GLM with inverse.gaussian family in R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

In my data set, I have 3 covariates ($V_1, V_2, V_3$) and response ($V_4$), generated by a program specifically written to generate random variables using an Inverse Gaussian distribution, in which $ \sigma^2 = 1 $ and $ \mu = \frac{1}{(\beta_0 + \beta_1 \cdot V_1 + \beta_2 \cdot V_2 + \beta_3 \cdot V_3)^\frac{1}{2}} $, where $ \boldsymbol \beta $ is the coefficient vector.

When I use the command `fit <- glm(V4 ~ V1 + V2 + V3, family = inverse.gaussian)`, R gives 2 errors:

```
Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting value
In addition: Warning message:
In sqrt(eta) : NaNs produced
```

The first one seems to be something specific to the Inverse Gaussian family for GLM, as I haven't gotten that error when I use the same command for other families.

I don't know why the second is thrown, as all such $ \eta = \boldsymbol \beta^T {\bf V} $ lie in the interval $ (0, 8) $.

If I manually use `start = c(1, 1, 1, 1)`, then it proceeds without errors but has the solution $ \hat{\boldsymbol \beta} = [2.491 \ 0.156 \ 0.572 \ 1.170 ]$, which is definitely not right as I used $ \boldsymbol \beta = [0.759 \ 0.825 \ 0.916 \ 0.972] $ to generate the data. The data set contains 1,000 tuples, so the randomness of the generation shouldn't allow the solution for $ \hat{\boldsymbol \beta} $ to vary by that much. When I have done this for other families, the difference bewteen any one element of $ \hat{\boldsymbol \beta} $ and $ \boldsymbol \beta $ hasn't been more than $ 0.05 $ for a data set of 1,000 tuples.

What should I do to correct this and properly estimate $ \hat{\boldsymbol \beta }$? For those curious, I am running a GLM on a data set where I already know $ \boldsymbol \beta $ for the purpose of testing a program.